# encoded search terms with %20

Tags: permalinks, search, encoding

```
<form class="search-form" action="<?php echo home_url( '/suche/' ); ?>" method="get">

    <input type="text" name="s" class="s" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>" />
```

this is in my `searchform.php` template.

Any ideas why when searching for e.g. "Graphic Design" it searches for "Cool%20Car" and replaces the space with an encoded `%20`?

This of course doesn't return any results because there is no text as "Cool%20Car" on my blog.

Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: You could change the 'method' to POST...

Answer (score 2):

This happens because search strings gets url encoded in order for the URL to be valid. You can reverse this with `urldecode`.

Comment: But this seems weird. Has never happened to me on other Wordpress Sites I made. Or at least it worked with the search terms. In my case the `search.php` holds `Cool%20Car` as term and not `Cool Car` as it's supposed to. I know the url must be encoded but why are the terms on my search.php site still encoded?

Comment: As usual - try to deactivate all plugins, and switch to default theme. If it doesn't happen there then there is something with your plugins/theme and then turn them on one by one and see which one gives u problems.

Comment: It's not fault of any plugins as it seems. Any other idea what could cause that?

Comment: What about theme?

Comment: Well, the only functions that could have anything to do with this are those … http://cl.ly/code/121u2I2F2X2K

However I tried to comment-out them one by one and it didn't make a difference. And as you can see of course the search-form.php template that is posted above in my question.